# mp3 file won't play on the server

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services

I am building a website for a friend of mine.  It involves playing music from a playlist of mp3 files.  I am able to play the mp3 files on my localhost, but not on the server. Would anyone have any thoughts on where I am failing?

Web page:
http://52.15.221.80/efs-mount-point/sampledir/jaelen/

Jquery and Mp3 files:
http://52.15.221.80/efs-mount-point/sampledir/jaelen/js/

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mediaPath = '/'` in your index.js file. Thus when you try to play *01KEEPITG.mp3* (for example), the browser loads http://52.15.221.80**/01KEEPITG.mp3** that is not exist. You need to use `'/efs-mount-point/sampledir/jaelen/js/'` value for the `mediaPath` field to set `src` attribute of your HTML `<autio>` tag correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you trying to access http://52.15.221.80/01KEEPITG.mp3 which is not found 404 on the server. but actual link is http://52.15.221.80/efs-mount-point/sampledir/jaelen/js/01KEEPITG.mp3

Your mp3 link should be `/js/01KEEPITG.mp3`

append /js/ to your mp3 src

your audio tag should be like this `<audio preload="" id="audio1" controls="controls" src="/js/01KEEPITG.mp3">Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio!</audio>`

You have permission error for mp3 file. please check that too

Comment: @maxmarbukh you can accept answer if  it worked. thanks